# Can you change the value of a virtual property in the class in which the property is first declared?

Tags: c#, properties, virtual

Now, I know that I could just change it in a derived class, however, because of the context, I cannot (it would require a huge modification in lots of other classes if I did that). I need to change this property's value based on something I compute in the main class AFTER initializing it's property in a derived class.

Regular assignment doesn't work. Also, you cannot get the REF of a C# property. I am using the auto getters and setters for properties, I have tried setting them in the old way too, to no avail.

```
MainClass{
    protected virtual long virtualPropertyIWannaChange { get; set; }


    public changeVariable(List<long> thisListIsReadFromAFile){
         foreach (long value in thisListIsReadFromAFile){
            if(condition)
               virtualPropertyIWannaChange+= someOtherValue;

         }
    }
}

ChildClass : MainClass{
    protected override long virtualPropertyIWannaChange => 1000;
}
```

I want to change the virtual variable's value in the "changeVariable" function, if the condition holds.
If I assign it like this, no warning is thrown, no error is thrown, but the property's value doesn't actually change. Any bit of help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to format the code you're presenting - it's *really* hard to read at the moment. It would also help if you'd provide some more context for this... *why* do you want to change the value of a virtual property in the situation where that *isn't* the "implementing" property anyway because it's overridden? What cares about the value, and why?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the welcome. I need to have it changed in order to accomodate for a situation that sometimes occurs in which the initial assignment of the variable (made in the ChildClass) needs to be slightly corrected. This property is used in the MainClass for many computations and it's quintessential. Now, I cannot just make these computations with another global variable that uses the corrected value, as the property is used in other derived classes, and it would mean changing everything. Can't give that much context since it's at work and confidential.

Comment: "I need to have it changed in order to accomodate for a situation that sometimes occurs in which the initial assignment of the variable (made in the ChildClass) needs to be slightly corrected." But you're assigning to a property - and the value you *retrieve* from that property will be retrieved from the overriding implementation anyway. It would really help if you could provide *actual* code instead of *pseudocode* too. What you've shown so far wouldn't compile - and not following .NET naming conventions doesn't help anyone trying to read it, either.

Comment: Fundamentally, if you've got a getter override that returns a constant value, there's *nothing* you can do to change the value returned by that property. If you don't want to return a constant value, don't implement it that way,.